# upgrade Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1. Issue with SQL script

Tags: sql, sitecore, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150812 to Sitecore 8.1.

I have downloaded "Sitecore 8.1 Upgrade Guide" here: 
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Initial_Release.aspx

I got stuck on the following step from this guide :

> 8. Upgrade the SXP database schemas:
>      SQL Server: Execute the SXP81_BeforeInstall.sql script on the reporting databases.

I got following error message in Management Studio when I run script on Master or Web database :

> Cannot find the object "dbo.Trail_Interactions" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

And also some other similar issues.

I have two different environments with Sitecore 8.0 and neither have those objects: `dbo.Trail_Interactions`, `dbo.FailureDetails` and so on (which are used in SQL script).

How can I finish upgrading successfully?

Comment: It sounds like your reporting databases are not setup correctly. Are these fresh Sitecore 8 installations or are they upgraded from a previous version? I have 2 clean installs and those tables are in the reporting database.

Comment: @RichardSeal, what does mean "reporting database"? Are you talking about Master and Web databases?

Comment: The reporting database is the SQL Server database that is used to report on the analytics of the site. It will normally be called `{Sitename}Sitecore_reporting". Make sure you are running the script on that DB and not the master or web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the script should only be run on the reporting database. The reporting database is the one defined by the connection string name `reporting` in `ConnectionStrings.config`.

```
<add name="reporting" connectionString="{connection string}"/>
```

The database is by default named something like either `Sitecore_Analytics` or `Sitecore_reporting`.